# determine suitable values for the parameters of the distance function for this graph

Tags: r, machine-learning, data-mining

Hi I've been learning data mining and came across this question. I couldn't seem to figure it out myself.

So we have an undirected graph(without attributes) G = (V,E) and want to detect nodes that are outliers within that graph.
an outlier O in dataset D is defined as:

```
|{o'|dist(o,o'}≤ r}|/|D|≤ π, where D = V.
```

How can we define the distance function `dist` between
a pair of nodes? How can we determine suitable values for the parameters `r` and `π`?

Comment: The distance between two nodes in a graph could be defined as the `number_of_intermeidate_nodes + 1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The distance between two nodes in a graph could be defined as

`number_of_intermeidate_nodes + 1`

For Determining r and π ,

It can be done empirically that best suits your data.Try for different values of r and π